# Net Neutrality would really stop the ISP's menace & bring Freedom of Internet

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

This is related to freedom of internet campaign brought to us by StackOverFlow community and we are asked for joining the hands for Net Neutrality. [Standing up for Net Neutrality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/30/raise-voice-proclaim-need-net-neutrality/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=system-message&utm_campaign=netneutrality)

Is this worth If we join In? Can we have sharepoint.stackexchange individuals's point of view on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a StackExchange-wide matter, which can be further debated/discussed/questioned in SE's Meta. The main-topic would be this one: [Net Neutrality and Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297816/net-neutrality-and-stack-overflow-stack-exchange) while this would be the chat discussion of the topic: [Discussion on question by Shog9: Net Neutrality and Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1114/discussion-on-question-by-shog9-net-neutrality-and-stack-overflow-stack-exchan).

As this is SE-wide, there's no specific need to bring up the "origin" of the participant in the discussion - we are all equals also in SE, ain't we! In other words, to answer more precisely, it's a topic one can freely participate. However, if you truly want to make even a slight impact, you'd want to focus your efforts (also) towards FCC as the *How You Can help* -section of your link describes.

---

Personally I feel this has only a positive intention, and at least I'll keep an eye on the discussion. The raise of awareness is a major step in the campaign. However it is, as said, a one's personal matter whether to support the campaign with a further input.